# SQL Syntax error running action Query through VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to build this query through VBA instead of building it in Access and running a docmd.openquery. That seemed to me like the easier route, but I wanted to work on my SQL. Obviously that didn't work as intended if I am here lol.
So, I am trying to take the Date values of 14 text boxes on our JobTicket form and insert them into another table, Tbl_Schedule. This table is not a part of the Query that is the record source for the JobTicket form. I am worried that attempting to add this table in will overload the Query, as it is already very full. When I try to quickly navigate to the last field in that Query the text writes on top of itself, and then Access goes not responding while it clears up the text and loads the last couple fields. Adding another 56 fields to that seems like a recipe for disaster. I will post the SQL I have written below.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Tbl_Schedule (Date_Scheduled1, Date_Scheduled2, Date_Scheduled3, Date_Scheduled4, Date_Scheduled5, Date_Scheduled6, Date_Scheduled7, " & _
                                      "(Date_Scheduled8, Date_Scheduled9, Date_Scheduled10, Date_Scheduled11, Date_Scheduled12, Date_Scheduled13, Date_Scheduled14)" & _
             "VALUES (#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled1_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled2_JobTicket] & "#, " & _
                    "(#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled3_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled4_JobTicket] & "#, " & _
                    "(#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled5_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled6_JobTicket] & "#, " & _
                    "(#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled7_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled8_JobTicket] & "#, " & _
                    "(#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled9_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled10_JobTicket] & "#, " & _
                    "(#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled11_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled12_JobTicket] & "#, " & _
                    "(#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled13_JobTicket] & "#,#" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled14_JobTicket] & "#)"
```

Table being inserted into: Tbl_Schedule

Fields being inserted into: Date_Scheduled1 -to- Date_Scheduled14

Getting data from text boxes: Txt_DateScheduled1_JobTicket -to- Txt_DateScheduled14_JobTicket on Frm_JobTicket

Any other questions that would assist you in assisting me please feel free to ask! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `...Date_Scheduled5, Date_Scheduled6, Date_Scheduled7, )" & _` That closing parenthesis doesn't belong there.  Also you need to concatenate the values in `"VALUES (" & [Forms]![Frm_JobTicket]![Txt_DateScheduled1_JobTicket] & ","...` etc.  And if the values are dates you need to research how to insert date values correctly.

Comment: If you really must use dynamic SQL here, see [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271). But... don't.

Comment: I have made all of the proposed changes, and thank you for that tid bit about inserting date values using SQL. I had completely forgotten you have to tell it if your data is certain types. However, I am still getting errors. I am replacing the code above in the post with those updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL has its uses, but this is not one of them.

Using DAO methods makes your code so much simpler and easier to read and debug.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim frm As Access.Form

' for readability
Set frm = Forms!Frm_JobTicket

' open table for adding record(s)
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tbl_Schedule", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

rs.AddNew
rs!Date_Scheduled1 = frm!Txt_DateScheduled1_JobTicket
rs!Date_Scheduled2 = frm!Txt_DateScheduled2_JobTicket
' etc.
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

With enumerated field names like these, you can also use a loop:

```
Dim i As Long

rs.AddNew
For i = 1 To 14
    rs("Date_Scheduled" & i) = frm("Txt_DateScheduled" & i & "_JobTicket")
Next i
rs.Update
```

Comment: I am headed out of the office as I type this, but I will try this fix tomorrow morning. I am relatively new to Access in general, and have seen this DAO method but it seemed much more complicated than VBA to someone with 0 coding experience like me! This does seem much simpler than what I was trying lol. Could you recommend me anywhere to read up on DAO basics?

Comment: I firstly have to say thank you, as I got in this morning and set to work on this. It worked instantly, and was definitely not as hard to wrap my head around as I thought. All though, after scheduling a few different items now I am getting a 'Data Type Conversion Error'. I am not quite sure why, as I hadn't even changed the day I was using to test it. It highlights 
 
 `rs("Date_Scheduled" & i) = frm("Txt_DateScheduled" & i & "_JobTicket")` . 

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to consider *normalizing* your data so that part of your problem is removed entirely. Instead of having DateScheduled1_JobTicket, DateScheduled2_JobTicket etc., it might be better to have another table which fills vertically instead of horizontally, perhaps with fields like ID, Item, JobTicketNumber, ScheduledDate.

Then, fill this table with a row for each item/sku/product, and date.  You'll have 14 rows for scheduled tickets for each item/sku/product instead of 14 columns, and this will also solve your future problem of adding 56 fields. The benefit is that you can present the job ticket schedule rows by using *continuous forms* (in a list). Even better, you can put this continuous form with dates as a *subform* on your item/sku/product main form, which will then show as a neat list of scheduled tickets that will automatically change as you scroll through item/sku/products.

If you don't use continuous forms, you can still use an unbound approach as you're using now. One benefit is that it will be much easier when you need to add future JobTicket numbers, since you can just add more rows instead of adding fields and having to do additional design work.

If you want to view data in the flattened way that you built your table, you can use a Crosstab query to present it as you have in your table, but the underlying data will be much better stored in a normalized format.

Note that you don't need to concatenate a string as you did above; just leave the **Forms!Form!Control** reference *expression* directly in the query and you have a nice parameterized query that will execute just fine, so long as there are dates in those controls (text box, drop down etc).

ex.

```
Insert Into (MyDateField) Values (Forms!MyForm!MyDateControl);
```

No dynamic SQL needed.

Comment: As far as normalizing goes this is as good is it is going to get in this DB. Our company has 40 different process we could apply to any given part, with multiple parts at 14 processes. Each of those steps needs a schedule date and an actual run date, as well as time taken and scrap. The continuous form idea sounds nice, but I don't think it would work for me here. We have some sales orders with 20-30 items on them. 280-420 rows per large sales order doesn't seem great. Wouldn't that go against normalization anyway, since the only thing changing between those 14 rows is a date field each time?

Comment: It appears that each part could have many processes, and each process could be used on many different parts. This creates a classic "many-to-many" scenario. In this scenario, the table I suggest above is called a "junction" table in SQL. You could even add a column for your sales order number. Collect the data in your continuous form (easy to use), then you can display differently on your Sales Order pdf/printed report to save space (comma delimited line, for example).